# Creating a subclass of SKShapeNode

Tags: swift, xcode7, skshapenode

```
class ColorRectangle: SKShapeNode {

    var width: CGFloat!
    var height: CGFloat!
    var rectColor: UIColor!

    convenience init(rectOfSize: CGSize, colorOfRectangle rectColor: UIColor) {

        super.init(rectOfSize: rectOfSize)

        self.width = rectOfSize.width
        self.height = rectOfSize.height
        self.rectColor = rectColor

        self.fillColor = rectColor
        self.strokeColor = rectColor
    }

}
```

Can't get the initializer right.
What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your initializer like this:

```
class ColorRectangle: SKShapeNode {

    var width: CGFloat!
    var height: CGFloat!
    var rectColor: UIColor!

    convenience init(rectOfSize: CGSize, colorOfRectangle rectColor: UIColor) {

        self.init()

        self.init(rectOfSize: rectOfSize)

        self.rectColor = rectColor

        self.fillColor = rectColor
        self.strokeColor = rectColor
    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly does the self.init() does in the initializer?

Comment: I'd also like to know, what's the purpose of the self.init()?